# add unpublished content to pane

Tags: 7, users, panels, chaos-tool-suite

As the maintainers of panels are not really [reacting](http://drupal.org/node/1294792), my questions here:

I am creating panel-nodes which should be filled with existing content.  I need to have a preview functionality, so the user can add the panel-node and the unpublished content, review it, and finally publish everything.

as admin (user/1) I can do so without any problems, but other authed user with the permission to add all content-types etc. cannot. 
they can open the dialog add content to pane > exisiting node. they can choose the unpublished node in the autocomplete field.  but after submitting the form (Finish) they get the message "Invalid node". this happens only with the unpublished nodes.

Is that a bug or am I missing something?

update: http://drupal.org/node/1294792

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only could solve it by giving the user the `administer nodes` permission. any permission control modules wouldnt help.

update:
this wont be fixed :(

-> http://drupal.org/node/1294792#comment-5193104

Answer (score 0):

I've never used panels, but it can be a permission problem. As far as I know, to view and publish unpublished content you need to have set the "administer nodes" permission. To let some roles manage certain unpublished content types without granting them more than they needed, once (in D6) I successfully used the [view_unpublished](http://drupal.org/project/view_unpublished) and [Publish content](http://www.drupal.org/project/publishcontent) modules.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you, but even if I add specified permissions, panels (or ctools) will still check for the "administer nodes", if we assume that this is the problem.

Comment: Not so sure: content access is complex and you can always hook it. If I were you I would give it a try creating a sandbox copy of site, granting administer nodes permission to roles and see if that is the problem or a bug.

Comment: I have tried both modules but it doesnt work ;(